# Can't connect to Google Cloud SQL (postgres) from App Engine with node.js and Prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, prisma

In my `app.yaml` I've got the following:

```
DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://USER:PWD@localhost:5432/DATABASE?host=/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME"
```

The service user, that is associated with this app has, I think, a needed permission:
[image]

But I keep getting the error:
 `` Can't reach database server at `/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME ``

The database is perfectly accessible from whitelisted IPs, so the problem is somewhere in this config.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend you to have a look at this related GitHub Issue:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11171

There are several comments for probable solutions

Comment: @NurulSundarani yeah, I've seen this one, but enabling the Cloud SQL Admin API did not help me. I guess My issue is different from the one described

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, but might be helpful for others.

I have moved from App Engine to Cloud Run with this Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile

# base image
FROM node:18-alpine3.18

# create & set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src

# copy source files
COPY . /usr/src

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

COPY . .

# start app
RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 5000
CMD npm run start
```

Do not forget to add an SQL connection when deploying a new revision
[image]

And note this line in your app.ts: `server.listen({ port: 5000, host: '0.0.0.0' });`, the "host" parameter is crucial, otherwise the container won't start.

Hope it helps someone.